# How to resize scrollView and UILabel placed on it with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have screen in my application, which displays some multiline information.
Before autolayout, I manually set size of ScrollView and UILabel
But now, I can't do it, with autolayout, and I want to keep autolayout.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.